# prototype property of an object in javascript

Tags: javascript

In this code,

```
obj1 = { // this is a car object
    make:  "Eagle"
    model: "Talon TSi"
    year:  1993
}

f = function(make, model, year){
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
}
```

If I need to override a `function` type object `window['Object']['toString]`  for `obj1` and `f`, then I would say,

```
 obj1.toString = 'something';
```

and

```
 f.prototype.toString = 'something';  //and then 'new f()' to create car object
```

Here, I see that, here `obj1` and `f` are child of same `function` type object(`window['Object']`) , but `prototype` property **is introduced** for `Function` type object `f` only but not for `Object` type object `obj1`.

Why `prototype` property is introduced/required to override using `Function` type objects but not for `Object` type objects?

*Note: Beginner in Javascript*

Comment: Because `prototype` is a property of functions (that you would usually use as constructors). Every object has an internal `[[Prototype]]` though.

Comment: Also, objects don't inherit from their own, public *prototype* but from their constructor's *prototype* (i.e. the one referenced by their internal `[[Prototoype]]` property).

Comment: I have really no idea what you are asking. What do you mean by "override"? What's the expected result? And no, `f` is not an `Object`, it's a `Function`.

Comment: You need to do `f.prototype.toString = function(){ /* your toString fn */};` and then use *f* to create the instances.

Comment: @Bergi Do you mean, for code, `obj2 = new f();`, where `obj1` and `obj2` are `Object`'s but `f` is not an `Object`?

Comment: @overexchange: They're all objects, but `f` is a `Function` object, `obj1` is an `Object` object, and `obj2` is an `f` object. As they're all objects, you can put arbitrary properties on all of them. They're no different in that regard. I still don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why prototype property is introduced/required to override using
>   function type objects but not for object type objects?

The prototype is like a template that will be used for the future creation of objects.  It's used with constructor functions that will create new objects with the `new` operator.  So, if you want to modify all objects that are ever created from a particular constructor, then you modify the `prototype` of that constructor.

That is different than modifying just an existing object that is already created.  To modify just that object, you can just directly modify the object itself, not the prototype.

So, whether to modify the object itself of the prototype depends upon what type of change you want to occur.  To modify a single instance of an object that is already created, you just modify that object directly, not the prototype.  To modify all objects every created from a given constructor, you modify the prototype.

You can modify the prototype to change an object, but when you do so, you will modify all objects, not just the one instance.  It is generally considered risky to modify a generic prototype like the `Object` prototype unless you are just adding polyfills for methods that are already standardized.  It would be safer to either modify only an instance or to create your own derived object that has the functionality you want.

In addition, `toString()` is a function, not a string that is meant to be called as a function and return a string.  To be compatible with the existing design of that, you need to follow that same scheme.

---

Your `obj` object is a specific instance of an object.  To modify it, you can just modify that object directly.  It has a prototype internally, but if you modify that, you will modify all objects that were made from the same prototype, not just modify this one object.  Sometimes that is your purpose, but in this case, it seems like you're just trying to modify `obj1`, not other objects too.

```js
    var obj1 = { // this is a car object
        make:  "Eagle",
        model: "Talon TSi",
        year:  1993
    }

    obj1.toString = function() {return "something";}

    document.write(obj1.toString());
```

And, the for your function `f`, since it is a constructor, you can set the `.toString` method on the prototype and it will affect all objects created with that constructor.

```js
f = function(make, model, year){
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
}

f.prototype.toString = function() {return "something else"}


document.write(new f("ford", "f", 2015).toString());
```

Keep in mind there's a difference between modifying the prototype of a constructor from which new objects will be created and modifying an existing instance of an object that is already created.  You have to know which type of oepration is appropriate and do it differently depending.

---

Since you seem to be still confused about where to define a property, here are some guidelines:

1. If it's a function that works all by itself and does not require an instance of anything to operate on (something like `Date.now()`), then that's a static function (it doesn't operate on an instance of some type of object and doesn't require that anyone previously created some object before it can be useful), then it's static and it should be defined in a static way which would either be as a global function on it's own such as `parseInt()` or a namespaced global function such as `Date.now()`.
2. If it's a function that operates on an instance of an object and it makes sense that it should be called like `obj.func1()`, then you can either define it on the prototype or you can assign it to the object in the constructor.  The usual scheme is to define it on the prototype as this offers some advantages.  The debate between using the prototype and assigning methods in the constructor is a completely other topic which is the subject or many other posts and threads.  My take on this debate is to use the `prototype` unless you have a specific reason not to (such reasons are rare).
3. If it's a static data value that does not belong to any specific instance of an object (such as a counter used to auto-increment ID values), then it should likely be either defined as a variable in a private closure or as a property on a static object, not on any prototype.
4. If it's an instance data variable that is meant to exist only on an instance of a specific type of object, then assign it an initial value in the constructor.  You generally do not want to put this on the prototype because properties on the prototype are shared by all instances which is not what you want for an "instance" variable.
5. If it's an instance data variable that is not assigned to all objects of this type, but is only sometimes assigned to the object, then it can be assigned either in one of the methods of that object as in `this.someProp = "foo";` or it can be assigned outside of any method as in `obj1.someProp = "foo";`.  Not, this type of one-off property is less common that the other types.  Usually all objects of a given type have a common list of properties and methods.

So, here's an overall example:

```
// constructor function
function myObj(parm1) {
    // initialize a couple properties of instance data
    this.data = parm1;
    this.status = "closed";
}

// define static properties
myObj.openCounter = 0;
myObj.debug = false;

// define a static method
myObj.log = function(msg) {
    if (myObj.debug) {
        console.log.apply(console, arguments);
    }
};

// define instance methods on the prototype
myObj.prototype = {
    isOpen: function() {
       return this.status === "open";
    },
    open: function() {
        // do something to open the object
        ++myObj.openCounter;
        this.status = "open";
        myObj.log("opening: ", this);
    },
    close: function() {
        // do something to close the object
        this.status = "closed";
        myObj.close("closing: ", this);
    }

};
```

Comment: @RobG - Yeah, I misunderstood what the OP was doing.  Working on fixing.

Comment: The actual question is "*Why prototype property is introduced/required to override using function type objects but not for object type objects*" which I think is off topic for here, or maybe needs further explanation.

Comment: @jfriend00 For your point: "you modify the `prototype` of that constructor."### we have other members like `Object.__defineSetter__`, here `__defineSetter__`  does not sit under  `prototype`. Now, we can say, `obj = new Object();`

Comment: @overexchange - I do not understand what that latest comment means.  `Object.prototype.__defineSetter__()` is deprecated and non-standard and explicitly removed from the Web standards.  There are some utility methods such as `Object.create()` which are global functions.  They are available globally on the `Object` object and are not instance methods.  You call them globally as in `Object.create(...)`, not on a specific object as in `obj1.create(...)`.  Functions are objects and can have their own properties or methods. If they are not on the prototype, then they are static/global methods.

Comment: @jfriend00  why function type `Object` has some methods outside `prototype` and some methods within `prototype`. What does it signify ?

Comment: @overexchange - see the latest edit to my previous comment.  It is the difference between instance methods (on the prototype) and static methods (on the object itself).  A static method is just a utility function that can be called without creating an object of that type.  For example, `Date.now()` returns the current epoch time count in milliseconds, not a Date object and does not require creating a Date object in order to use it.  Similar thing for `Object.create()`.  They are just functions attached to a constructor as a means of organizing them in that that constructor's namespace.

Comment: @jfriend00   What does it mean to create a property for object `obj2` ? I mean,  `obj2 = new f();` `obj2.p1 = 'something';`.  Is `p1` a static or instance property of `obj2`?

Comment: @overexchange - In your example, `p1` is a property of the `obj2` object.  It only exists on that object.  Since `obj2` is an instance of `f()`, I would call it an instance property because it only exists on an instance.  It is a little bit of an "in between" because it only exists on this one instance of the `f` object, not all instances..  But, at this point you're just looking for a semantic answer which is not really  relevant.  Static methods of an object exist when only the constructor exists and there are no instances of the object yet.  Instance properties exist on instances.

Comment: @overexchange—when you assign to an object property, it is always created on the instance. If a property of that name doesn't exist on the instance, it's created, even if the instance has a property of that name on its `[[Prototype]]` chain.

Comment: @jfriend00 For your point: "*they are not on the prototype, then they are static/global methods*", So, am confused to differentiate between 1) `make` property in `this.make` in `f` constructor 2) `f.prototype.toString` which is coming under `f.prototype` 3) `obj2.p1` where `p1` is created  after creation of `obj2` from `f`. **How do I differentiate these 3 properties ?**

Comment: @overexchange - See explanation I added to the end of my answer above.  If you don't understand the distinction between static properties and instance properties after reading my description, then you must sort that out or you will not understand what goes where.

Comment: @jfriend00 So, `this.data = parm1;` is an instance property but **cannot** be inherited and object literal pointed by `myObj.prototype` is an instance property and **can** be inherited.

Comment: @overexchange - all instance properties are inherited either way.  When a derived class calls the parent constructor, the instance properties set in the constructor will then be set and available to the derived object too.